# bash script to split and reverse filenames

Tags: bash

A bash script request(or fish script). I have a bunch of files like:

```
name - lastname.info
names  - lastnames.info
name & name - lastname & lastname.info
```

but I want to change all of them to:

```
lastname - name.info
lastnames - names.info
lastname & lastname - name & name - lastname & lastname.info
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

going by your sample data, you have `" - "` as the delimiter, so

```
for file in *; do
    ext=${file##*.}
    no_ext=${file%.*}
    name=${no_ext% - *}
    lastname=${no_ext##* - }
    mv "$file" "$lastname - $name.$ext"
done
```

For the gory details, see http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop to loop through all the files in the cwd, then use the [cut](http://www.ss64.com/bash/cut.html) utility to parse the file name based on the '-' delimiters to get first and last name (I then re-cut to parse out the file name extension), then use [tr](http://ss64.com/bash/tr.html) to remove the leading/trailing spaces. Finally concatenate, and you've got your new file name:

```
for file in *
do
    fname=`echo $file | cut -d '-' -f 1 | tr -d ' '`
    lname=`echo $file | cut -d '-' -f 2 | cut -d '.' -f 1 | tr -d ' '`
    newname=$lname' - '$fname.info
    echo $newname
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming all your files are in one directory:

```
for f in lastname*
do
    mv $f `echo $f | sed 's/lastname/name/'`
done
```

If your files are anywhere in the hierarchy, you will have to use the `find` command but the basic idea remains.

Comment: Do you mean to replace your sed substitution with the actual first and last names from the file name? Otherwise, you're only handling the case where file names are comprised of the strings 'name' and 'lastname'..

Comment: This is not going to work, you need to quote your parameters to `mv` to account for the spaces.